# image in a canvas disappearing when moves(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to move my image inside the canvas by changing the axis coordinates, but as they move my image starting to disappear. The Gun class represent the infrastructure component that I want to include in the canvas.

```js
var gun;
var canvas;

function AddGun() {
  gun = new Gun(100, 100, "images/gun.png", 0, 100);
}
class Gun {
  constructor(width, height, source, x, y) {
    canvas = document.getElementById("for-js");
    canvas.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = source;
    img.onload = function() {
      canvas.context.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="AddGun()">
  <div class="game-block">
    <canvas id="for-js"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though in the provided code I don't see where the image would be dynamically moved. I imagine it's because somewhere your code moves the image outside the canvas boundaries. This would be a likely cause of the image starting to disappear.